# XML retrieving from a URL to CSV

Tags: python

Simply, I need to retrieve current currencies and rates from central bank of europe which is in XML format and convert it to CSV file using python. It creates me a file but it does not write the correct things I need.

XML follows here:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?

This is my code but it does not work please help guys.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import csv

kurzbanky_xml = requests.get("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml")
root = ET.fromstring(kurzbanky_xml.text)


with open('banka.csv','w',newline='') as Currency_Rate:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(Currency_Rate)
    csvwriter.writerow(['currency','rate'])

    for member in root.iterfind('Cube'):
        cur = cube.attrib['currency']
        rat = cube.attrib['rate']
        csvwriter.writerow([cur,rat])
```

Comment: http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/ this may help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "does not work" mean? Please read [ask]. Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: What is `cube` in your code?

Comment: "Does not work" means that it does not write proper things to the new CSV file as I mentioned. @Alderven ---> cube is name of tag in XML.

Comment: "Does not write proper things to the new CSV file" still isn't clear. Does the file not get created? Does it get created, but nothing gets written to it? Does it have the wrong content written to it? If so, what's the content that does get written? Does it get _some of_ the correct content but it's missing data? Does the code fail to run? If so, what error do you see? Telling us what's not happening isn't as helpful as telling us what _is_ happening. Again, please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) lib to convert XML to JSON and then iterate over JSON:

```
import csv
import requests
import xmltodict

r = requests.get("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml").text
data = xmltodict.parse(r)['gesmes:Envelope']['Cube']['Cube']

with open('{}.csv'.format(data['@time']), 'w', newline='') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(['currency', 'rate'])

    for cur in data['Cube']:
        csvwriter.writerow([cur['@currency'], cur['@rate']])
```

Output `2019-03-27.csv` file:

```
currency,rate
USD,1.1261
JPY,124.42
BGN,1.9558
CZK,25.797
DKK,7.4664
GBP,0.85118
```

etc.

Comment: Wow thats great! Thank you for help and have one additional question. I would like to rename that CSV file ('banka.csv') exactly according to the current time which is written in that XML {<Cube time="2019-03-27">}. It should be in format --> YYYY-MM-DD.csv , so in this case 2019-03-27.csv. And everytime I launch that programe, it should update itself. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: See my updated answer